# Ubuntu 15.10 xrandr resolution error

Tags: drivers, ati, display-resolution, xrandr

im using ubuntu 15.10 64bit and a AMD HD 8560D Graphic card.

With the latest AMD Crimson 15.12 i only get a resolution of 2048x..... with no way to change it to a higher one.
The free radeon driver got the right resolution of 2560x1440@60.

So i tried xrandr:

```
cvt 2560 1440 60
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60" 312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode DFP1 2560x1440_60
```

After this command i get an error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  141 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  33
Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

Any ideas what i could do?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions
Try letting it detect resolutions dynamically.